# Oracle: how to add minutes to a timestamp?

Tags: oracle, date, timestamp, date-arithmetic

I need to add 30 minutes to values in a Oracle date column.  I do this in my SELECT statement by specifying

`to_char(date_and_time + (.000694 * 31)`

which works fine most of the time.  But not when the time is on the AM/PM border.  For example, adding 30 minutes to `12:30` [which is  PM] returns `1:00` which is AM. The answer I expect is `13:00`.  What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

All of the other answers are basically right but I don't think anyone's directly answered your original question.

Assuming that "date_and_time" in your example is a column with type DATE or TIMESTAMP, I think you just need to change this:

```
to_char(date_and_time + (.000694 * 31))
```

to this:

```
to_char(date_and_time + (.000694 * 31), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
```

It sounds like your default date format uses the "HH" code for the hour, not "HH24".

Also, I think your constant term is both confusing and imprecise.  I guess what you did is calculate that (.000694) is about the value of a minute, and you are multiplying it by the number of minutes you want to add (31 in the example, although you said 30 in the text).

I would also start with a day and divide it into the units you want within your code.  In this case, (1/48) would be 30 minutes; or if you wanted to break it up for clarity, you could write ( (1/24) * (1/2) ).

This would avoid rounding errors (except for those inherent in floating point which should be meaningless here) and is clearer, at least to me.

Comment: dont forget to see the answer with 40+ ratings below :)

Comment: I'm downvoting this. While practical in general, there are always chances of: 1) rounding errors, 2) errors with daylight savings time and other date/time caveats, 3) it's less maintainable than actual interval calculations.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Thank you for pointing out that a much better solution exists :) I suppose [Justin Cave's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/257399/715077) is the one you're refering to?

Answer (score 144):

In addition to being able to add a number of days to a date, you can use interval data types assuming you are on `Oracle 9i` or later, which can be somewhat easier to read,

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf
SELECT sysdate, sysdate + interval '30' minute FROM dual
SQL> /

SYSDATE              SYSDATE+INTERVAL'30'
-------------------- --------------------
02-NOV-2008 16:21:40 02-NOV-2008 16:51:40
```

Comment: +1 Wow, I never knew this...I can finally drop the ridiculous fractions of a day stuff!

Comment: This is really helpful and probably should be the accepted answer given the upvotes it has received.

Comment: the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot for this(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257324/oracle-how-to-add-minutes-to-a-timestamp#comment28355714_258555) comment which pointed to this answer!

Comment: This is a good answer, but I personally think [jtomaszk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17039496/715077) is more clear and to the point.

Comment: This method also maintains precision if your source value is a `TIMESTAMP` such as `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  Adding 30 / 24 / 60 to a TIMESTAMP will convert it to a DATETIME.

Comment: I like this, but it doesn't work when the interval is coming from a parameter or query result.

Comment: @Homer - I'm not sure I understand.  If your parameter is an `interval`, it should behave the same way.  If you are passing in a number and/or a unit, you probably want to use the `numToDSInterval` function to construct the interval rather than using the interval literal syntax.

Comment: @JustinCave - I didn't know about this function, thanks!

Answer (score 20):

```
UPDATE "TABLE" 
SET DATE_FIELD = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + interval '48' minute 
WHERE (...)
```

Where `interval` is one of

- YEAR
- MONTH
- DAY
- HOUR
- MINUTE
- SECOND

Comment: This works :) and your answer is much easier to read than the Oracle docs on [Interval Literals for 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221)

Answer (score 13):

from http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_add_a_day_hour_minute_second_to_a_date_value

The SYSDATE pseudo-column shows the current system date and time. Adding 1 to SYSDATE will advance the date by 1 day. Use fractions to add hours, minutes or seconds to the date

```
SQL> select sysdate, sysdate+1/24, sysdate +1/1440, sysdate + 1/86400 from dual;

SYSDATE              SYSDATE+1/24         SYSDATE+1/1440       SYSDATE+1/86400
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
03-Jul-2002 08:32:12 03-Jul-2002 09:32:12 03-Jul-2002 08:33:12 03-Jul-2002 08:32:13
```

Answer (score 13):

I prefer using an `interval` literal for this, because `interval '30' minute` or `interval '5' second` is a lot easier to read then `30 / (24 * 60)` or `5 / (24 * 60 * 69)`

e.g.

- `some_date + interval '2' hour`
- `some_date + interval '30' minute`
- `some_date + interval '5' second`
- `some_date + interval '2' day`

You can also combine several units into one expression:

- `some_date + interval '2 3:06' day to minute`

Adds 2 days, 3 hours and 6 minutes to the date value

The above is also standard SQL and also works in several other DBMS.

More details in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00221

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 5):

like that very easily

i added 10 minutes to system date and always in preference  use the Db server functions not custom one .

```
select to_char(sysdate + NUMTODSINTERVAL(10,'MINUTE'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Comment: I could not get the "interval '2' second" syntax to work with JDBC parameter replacement but this worked for me as I could make the number in the function call a replaceable parameter.

Answer (score 3):

If the data type of the field is date or timestamp, Oracle should always give the correct result if you add the correct number given in number of days (or a the correct fraction of a day in your case). So if you are trying to bump the value in 30 minutes, you should use :

```
select field + 0.5/24 from table;
```

Based on the information you provided, I believe this is what you tried to do and I am quite sure it works.

Comment: The above answer w/o using to_char on it provides just the default format, eg: 04-NOV-08.  Which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Can we not use this

```
SELECT date_and_time + INTERVAL '20:00' MINUTE TO SECOND FROM dual;
```

I am new to this domain.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that Oracle understands that the starting time is PM, and to specify the HH24 format mask for the final output.

```
SELECT to_char((to_date('12:40 PM', 'HH:MI AM') + (1/24/60) * 30), 'HH24:MI') as time
  FROM dual

TIME
---------
13:10
```

Note: the `'AM'` in the HH:MI is just the placeholder for the AM/PM meridian indicator. Could be also `'PM'`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle now has new built in functions to do this:

```
select systimestamp START_TIME, systimestamp + NUMTODSINTERVAL(30, 'minute') end_time from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're asking for, you want the HH24:MI format for to_char.

Answer (score 0):

To edit Date in oracle you can try

```
  select to_char(<columnName> + 5 / 24 + 30 / (24 * 60),
           'DD/MM/RRRR hh:mi AM') AS <logicalName> from <tableName>
```

Comment: `5 / 24` for 5 hours and `30 / (24 * 60)` for 30 minutes.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate + (1/24/60) * 30, 'dd/mm/yy HH24:MI am') from dual;
```

simply you can use this with various date format....

Comment: Why would you use the anti-meridian with HH24 format?