# How to change the value of the default systimestamp in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Is there a way to change the value of the default timestamp in oracle, please find the below output of the query and it is one day behind. The google is returning results only to change the format of the default systimestmap, but i need to change the value itself. Please suggest.

```
select systimestamp from dual
```

### SYSTIMESTAMP

12-02-17 07:29:26.843712000 PM +05:30

Comment: Whats your data/time on underlying OS?

Comment: @JSapkota : oh okie , i was not aware of this related to OS. it shows the wrong one ( its 12 the feb) as mentioned in the systimestamp. Thnks!! will find a unix admin to modify that.Anyway besides that, is there a way to change the value of systimestamp.

Comment: As you have noticed, the `systimestamp` is derived from underlying OS where the database resides.

Comment: Thanks a ton, it helped

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to provide your own value and turn in into a timestamp like this?

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('10-Sep-02 14:10:10.123000', 'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF')
   FROM DUAL;
```

Oracle documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm

Related question:
[Oracle: how to add minutes to a timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257324/oracle-how-to-add-minutes-to-a-timestamp)

Comment: Yeah, this is like converting, i thought to change the default systimestamp itself

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '2' SECOND FROM dual;
```

With this method you are able to add or remove 'second's, 'minute's, 'hour's and so on...

Hope this helps :-)